# How to measure or scale object to fit on other's object?

Tags: inkscape, snapping, measurement

I've got little problem here. Let's see, I want to make pizza slice like object, and I have made it.But when I want to make the object duplicate and rotate, it goes like this [image]

I want to know how to measure the pizza slice objects and make it fit to the circle shape in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for Inkscape

1. First decide how many slices you need. Let's say you want 6. There are 360° in a circle. You need to divide 360° by the number of slices you want, to calculate the angle you need.

360°/6=60°

2. Draw a circle, and set the start point to 0°, and the end point to 60°. And press the "Switch to Slice" button.

[image]

3. With the Select tool <kbd>S</kbd>, select the slice twice until the rotation handles appear, and with snapping enabled click and drag the rotation centre point to middle of the circle
4. Duplicate using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and rotate using the Transfrom panel <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to rotate 60°, hitting Apply to make the rotation. Repeat until complete.
5. If required, change the fill colour of each slice.

[image]